# Can we update git version in the Docker Image?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry

I'm using docker to install my dependencies. Using Node:10.13.0 as

`FROM: node:10.13.0`

All dependencies installed well except `Husky`.

And it shows the following:

```
Husky requires Git >=2.13.0. Got v2.11.0.   
husky > Failed to install
```

So, the problem is that the `git version` is below 2.13.

Searched for init git version in the docker file. But I don't get any solution.

Is any other way to set the git version in the docker file?.

Comment: What distro is that `node:10.13.0` derivation based on? (Find _its own_ Dockerfile, and look at the `FROM:` line). Use whatever package manager its upstream provides -- if it's `FROM ubuntu`, then `apt`; if it's `FROM alpine`, then `apk`; etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Next means `node:10.13.0` use debian9, aka `stretch`.

  ```
  $ docker run --rm node:10.13.0 cat /etc/issue
  Debian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l
  ```
- Next means `node:10.13.0` default use `git 2.11`.

  ```
  $ docker run --rm node:10.13.0 git --version
  git version 2.11.0
  ```

In fact, `git` in `debian 9` apt repo use the version 2.11, if you want to upgrade to a newer version, you could use `debian backports`, which means:

> Backports are packages taken from the next Debian release

By default, `backports` won't be used when use `apt`. You could use next sample to enable this.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:10.13.0
RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get -t stretch-backports install git -y
```

Verify it:

```
$ docker build -t mynodeimage .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM node:10.13.0
......
Successfully tagged mynodeimage:latest
$ docker run --rm mynodeimage git --version
git version 2.20.1
```

Comment: Getting `Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Could not connect to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (151.101.154.132)`. 
And Is there a way for **ubuntu** distribution?

Comment: Do you behind a proxy? What does `I used ubuntu distribution` mean? You mean your host is ubuntu?

Comment: No, not behind proxy. Debian and ubuntu are two of the Linux distribution right?

Comment: What's the output of `docker run --rm node:10.13.0 ping debian.map.fastlydns.net -c 4`? And your base image is debian, why you mention ubuntu to me?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I'm totally new to using docker. And now it's getting latest git version.

Comment: why this message is shown while build `debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed`.

Comment: @SuryaS See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023312/docker-having-issues-installing-apt-utils)